# Mailboxes on new server don't have INBOX prefix. How can I add it?

Tags: imap, apple-mail, dovecot

My web host moved my account from a cPanel system to a DirectAdmin system. They seem to have messed up my mailbox hierarchy in the move.

In Apple Mail I've always had the IMAP prefix set to INBOX. But on the new system, Mail doesn't see any of my mailboxes. If I remove the IMAP prefix, it does see my mailboxes. That would be fine except that my iOS devices don't see the mailboxes. They only see mailboxes with the INBOX prefix. I looked at my Mail settings in iOS and the IMAP prefix is empty.

My web host is trying to tell me the problem is on my side and that I should ask Apple for help . So I'm trying to troubleshoot the problem myself. Looking at the mail directory in my account I can see that my web host is using Dovecot. I don't have access to the dovecot.conf file. I'm wondering if there's a configuration setting they don't have set correctly. Looking at the Dovecot documentation I found the [imapc_list_prefix](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/mail_location/imapc/#core_setting-imapc_list_prefix) setting. Could it be that they don't have this set to "INBOX/"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having all mailboxes prefixed with INBOX was a quirk of Courier IMAP, and it's entirely normal for them to be unprefixed by default under other IMAP servers. Re-adding the IMAP account on your iOS device should make everything work properly.

---

If you *want* the prefix to be there for some reason, in Dovecot it's configured per-`namespace`. For example:

```
namespace inbox {
    separator = .
    prefix = INBOX.
    inbox = yes
}
```

But this shouldn't be necessary – with Dovecot you can directly create mailboxes under the IMAP root instead.

---

(Ignore the `imapc_list_prefix` setting; it is only used when Dovecot acts as an IMAP *client,* i.e. when it's proxying your connection to another IMAP server.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll pass that on to my web host. The problem with not having the INBOX prefix is that all of the mailboxes in my account show up as subfolders of the inbox in my mail app. That causes the unread count of the inbox to be the sum of the unread count in all the subfolders so I can't get a real count of unread messages in the inbox.

Comment: Uh, that sounds more like the problem with _having_ the INBOX prefix, rather than not having it. I use Dovecot with the default (unprefixed) configuration and have never seen this problem.

Comment: That is, if your host migrated the mailboxes 1:1 and put them all underneath INBOX like in the old system, then the easier way forward would be to just move them _out_ of INBOX into the root, which Dovecot would allow you to do.

Comment: I finally got around to re-adding my three IMAP accounts on one of my iPads. It made everything work properly as you said. Now, I just need to do it on my other iPad, my iPhone, my wife's iPad, and my wife's iPhone. ‍♂️ Thanks for that tip. I would never have expected that to do the trick since the IMAP prefix was already blank.